# Lutron Fan & Light dimmer switch wiring

Tags: dimmer-switch, fans

I have a hunter Fan/Light I am installing.  I purchased the pictured Lutron switch to control the fan/light.  My power source comes into the switch box and is wired as follows: Power source (Black) tied to Black on the switch; Power source (White) tied to the White wire running to the ceiling fan; Power source ground (Bare) tied to the Green switch wire and the bare ground wire running to the ceiling fan; The Red wire running to the ceiling fan is tied to the Red wire on the switch.  The black wire running to the ceiling fan is tied to the yellow wire on the switch.

At the ceiling box I connected the black wire from the switch to the black (Fan) on the fan motor, the red from the ceiling to the blue (Light) on the fan motor, the white from the ceiling to the white on the motor and tied all the grounds together.

Am I correct in the wiring here?  I've done one of these before but it's been a while.  The instructions with both the switch and the fan are not much help by any stretch!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That all looks correct. Does some part of it not work correctly?